# Bulk inserts in mongodb (mongoose) without duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb

A very simple question.

I want to bulk insert documents in mongodb (I am using mongoose as the ORM). I have heard about the **Model.collection.insert** for bulk inserts but am not able to understand how to use this method avoiding duplicates.

I want to check for duplicates using key in the document model

Thank you for taking the time to answer this!

Comment: would you please show  what you have tried so far ? that will help to give answer

Answer (score 0):

have you tried .save ?  here the example

```
var user = new Patient(req.body);

user.save(function (err, cb) {
    if (err) {
        return res.json(err);
    } else {
        res.json(cb);
    }
});
```